# Pay TeX expert to create XeLaTeX documents?

Tags: discussion

Through the TeX Q&A site, I've been learning from scratch while creating my own .tex documents. I'm doing ok and progressing slowly but I'd be glad to pay someone  more qualified than I to do this task.

How can I find and engage with candidates from this community (especially those who answered my questions in the Q&A site) whom are willing to receive payment for work to create XeLaTeX documents?

Comment: This has been asked as a question on the main site: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19553/where-to-find-people-for-hire-with-latex-skills-and-designer-skills

Answer (score 2):

After looking around the TeX Q&A website, I assume the best way to find candidates is to click on user profiles and look through their profile info or personal website to find a means to contact them and propose a possible job opportunity.